# applescript: Appropriately escape input in script invocation

Tags: terminal, keyboard, applescript, iterm

I have the following snippet in an `applescript`:

```
          tell current session of current tab of current window
              write text "watch -n1 'kubectl get pods | grep -i"  & input'
              split horizontally with default profile
              split vertically with default profile
          end tell
```

But this does not work given that I am getting the following error:

> script error: Expected end of line but found unknown token. (-2741)

I want the end result, given that I will be invoking the script as

```
myscript appname
```

To be

```
watch -n1 'kubectl get pods | grep -i appname'
```

Any suggestions?

**edit**: I have also tried this without success:

```
write text "watch -n1 "\kubectl get pods | grep -i & input\""
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me:

assuming that you grab input by having as a first line in your script the following:

```
on run {input}
```

Then you can perform within an `iTerm` window:

```
write text "watch -n1 " & "'"  & "kubectl get pods | grep -i " & input & "'"
```